# Unable to run 2 different flask apps on same server

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Here is my nginx config

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name site.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /var/www/site/env;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /var/www/site;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_MODULE app;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CALLABLE app;
    }

    location /site2 {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /var/www/site2/env;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /var/www/site2;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_MODULE app;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_CALLABLE app;
    }
}
```

When I visit site.com, sometimes I'm being served from /var/www/site, and other times from /var/www/site2. Also, when I try to visit site.com/site2, I'm sometimes being served from var/www/site2 and sometimes from /var/www/site.

What is the reason for this inconsistent behavior, and how to resolve it so that I can use 2 different flask apps without actually using 2 different domains?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example#MoinMoinonlinenow

Comment: Are you able to run both on the same domain now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are connecting both of your applications through the same socket unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock. You would have same problem if you used different domains.